# Hamiltonian for two optical fibers fused together

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

When two optical fibers A and B are brought close enough that there can be quantum tunneling between the two, we can write the "beam splitter" Hamiltonian as

$$H = a^\dagger b + b^\dagger a$$

[image]

If, instead, the two fibers are spliced together, such that (travelling from left to right) photons in B continue in B, but photons in A merge into B, how do I write the Hamiltonian for this?

My guess is

$$H = a b^\dagger.$$

It's not Hermitian, but maybe it's correct. I would be interested in references to any material that discusses something like this in the context of quantum optics and second quantisation representation. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Non-hermitian hamiltonians are *never* correct, unless you have losses (i.e. actual absorption) in your system.

Comment: Related: [Phase added on reflection at a beam splitter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185155/phase-added-on-reflection-at-a-beam-splitter/)

Comment: Hmm, ok I read the links, but still have no real sense of how to construct my Hamiltonian. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: start with the classical optics, build a hamiltonian formulation in terms of modes, and *then* quantize. There's nothing about your question that cannot be figured out first in the classical-optics arena and then brought back to the QM side, and then you can just do old-school classical optics instead of wondering about non-hermitian hamiltonians.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty I know that you deal with this stuff, so I am curious to understand how a beam-splitter Hamiltonian may work. Up to now, I only read descriptions of the BS device in terms of unitary matrices accounting for transition processes. A Hamiltonian $H$ would instead imply a true temporal process: is there a sort of time evolution? (Yes obviously!) If Yes, how is the evolutor operator $e^{-itH}$ related with the standard BS description?

Comment: (I might add that I am collaborating with a group of experimental physicists dealing with integrated optics and we have just submitted a joint  experimental paper about violation of CHSH inequality by photons with intraparticle entanglement... so my question is not matter of pure curiosity)

Comment: @ValterMoretti That's a pretty subtle area and well worth a dedicated thread. As far as "is there a sort of time evolution? (Yes obviously!)", don't discount the subtleties, particularly because to get to this two-mode Hilbert space you need to assume a narrowband quasi-monochromatic limit, which means that the spatial extent of each laser pulse is at least $\Delta x = c/\delta\omega$, for $\delta\omega$ the bandwidth of the mode. Depending on the configuration, $\Delta x$ might be many kilometers, so the time dependence is a tricky thing to deal with as the pulse passes the beam splitter.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: Is my question textbook material where I can find this specific example explained somewhere? Or it's more complicated than that?