# Phase shifts in different beam splitter designs

Tags: optics, reflection, interferometry

I am trying to understand how a Mach-Zehnder interferometer works. It seems that it will work whether we use two beam splitters that consist of either

1. glass prisms glued together
2. a sheet of glass with dielectric coating
3. a sheet of glass with a thin metallic coating

Let us ignore the slight optical path difference induced by light travelling inside glass (for a perfectly symmetric interferometer setup these delays will cancel each other anyway).

I can make sense of scenario 2 as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter#Phase_shift) - if light hits the dielectric beam splitter one of the outgoing beams must have a phase shift of $\pi$ so that energy is conserved (see derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter#Classical_lossless_beam_splitter)). More precisely, if light hits the beam splitter coming from the less dense medium (red), part of the light is reflected with a phase shift of $\pi$, whereas the transmitted part has no phase shift. But what exactly happens at the interface glass - dielectric so that no phase shift occurs (blue)?

[image]

To summarize I want to understand the amount of phase shift that each of these types of beam splitters induce as well as the mechanisms involved.

Comment: Is there an AR coating on the air/glass interface?

Comment: @Gilbert: No, the thick black line indicates the dielectric coating, or were you asking about the surfaces in general?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185155/phase-added-on-reflection-at-a-beam-splitter